# Android app data extract it is getting compilation error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, kotlin

```
fun clickFunction(view: View)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText txt = (EditText) clearFindViewByIdCache(R.id.editText);
    EditText pwd = (EditText) clearFindViewByIdCache(R.id.editText2);
    Log.i("info",txt.getText().toString());
}
```

I want to extract the values from the plain text view in *android studio 3.1.4* but i am not able to because I get an compilation error.

Comment: Hi Kapil, whats the compilation error?

Comment: The piece of code won't compile, because it's not Kotlin. It's a mix of Kotlin and Java. Also, `clearFindViewByIdCache()` is parameterless function. You can't use it like this.